# Poor Python Multiprocessing Performance

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I attempted to speed up my python program using the multiprocessing module but I found it was quite slow.
A Toy example is as follows:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager

class A:
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i

    def score(self, x):
        return self.i - x


class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.i_list = list(range(1000))
        self.A_list = []

    def run_1(self):
        for i in self.i_list:
            self.x = i
            map(self.compute, self.A_list) #map version
            self.A_list.append(A(i))

    def run_2(self):
        p = Pool()
        for i in self.i_list:
            self.x = i
            p.map(self.compute, self.A_list) #multicore version
            self.A_list.append(A(i))

    def compute(self, some_A):
        return some_A.score(self.x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    st = time.time()
    foo = B()
    foo.run_1()
    print("Map: ", time.time()-st)
    st = time.time()
    foo = B()
    foo.run_2()
    print("MultiCore: ", time.time()-st)
```

The outcomes on my computer(Windows 10, Python 3.5) is

Map:  0.0009996891021728516

MultiCore:  19.34994912147522

Similar results can be observed on Linux Machine (CentOS 7, Python 3.6).

I guess it was caused by the pickling/depicking of objects among processes? I tried to use the Manager module but failed to get it to work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's not the `map` that is slow, it seems to be the `self.A_list.append(A(i))`

Also you seem to use `map` incorrectly. It returns a value and you are not using it at all. Do you know what `map` is doing?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Both `map` and `append` are fast as can be seen from the first timing result. On the contrary, `p.map` is slow(the multiprocessing version). I did not use the return value of `map` because this is just an example to show the poor performance of `p.map` and I did not need the return value.

Answer (score 1):

Wow that's impressive (and slow!).

Yes, this is because Objects must be accessed concurrently by workers, which is costly.

So I played a little bit and managed to gain a lot of perf by making the compute method static. So basically, you don't need to share the B object instance anymore. Still very slow but better.

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager

class A:
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i

    def score(self, x):
        return self.i - x

x=0
def static_compute(some_A):
    res= some_A.score(x)
    return res


class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.i_list = list(range(1000))
        self.A_list = []

    def run_1(self):
        for i in self.i_list:
            x=i
            map(self.compute, self.A_list) #map version
            self.A_list.append(A(i))

    def run_2(self):
        p = Pool(4)
        for i in self.i_list:
            x=i
            p.map(static_compute, self.A_list) #multicore version
            self.A_list.append(A(i))
```

The other reason that makes it slow, to me, is the fixed cost of using Pool. You're actually launching a Pool.map 1000 times. If there is a fixed cost associated with launching those processes, that would make the overall strategy slow. Maybe you should test that with longer A_list (longer than the i_list, which requires a different algo).

Comment: Thanks. The static function is much faster. I think, though not compelling in this example, it will be helpful in my real application.

Answer (score 0):

The reasoning behind this is:

1. the map call is performed by **main**

*meaning when foo.run_1() is called. The **main** is mapping for itself.
much like telling your self what to do.

*when foo_run2() is called the **main** is mapping for max process capablilites of that pc. 
If your max process is 6, then the **main** is mapping for 6 Threads.
much like orginizing 6 people to tell you something.

Side Note:
if you use:

```
p.imap(self.compute,self.A_list)
```

the items will append in order to A_list